# Activity is destroyed when I start another activity without finishing the first activity

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling with this issue and I want to know if there is any option to know why an activity is being closed, I have checked if it was a low memory issue with Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); but everything looks fine.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I call the activities and when suddenly all the background activities are closed. In all the way from MainActivity to SketchActivity I'm not calling the finish(); method but when I start the SketchActivity from BoulderProfileActivity, all the activies are destroyed, except SketchActivity :

**MainActivity:**

```
 private void SendUserToFindBoulderActivity(){
    Intent boulderFindIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FindBouldersActivity.class);
    startActivity(boulderFindIntent);
}
```

**FindBouldersActivity:**

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent boulderProfileIntent = new 
         Intent(FindBouldersActivity.this,BoulderProfileActivity.class);
         boulderProfileIntent.putExtra("BoulderKey", BoulderKey);
         startActivity(boulderProfileIntent);
     }
 });
```

**BoulderProfileActivity:**

```
public void SendUserToSketchUpActivity(){
    Intent sketchIntent = new Intent(BoulderProfileActivity.this, SketchActivity.class);
    sketchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    if(sustituir==false) {
        sketchIntent.putExtra("BoulderKey", BoulderKey);
        sketchIntent.putExtra("Uri", ImageUri);
        sketchIntent.putExtra("sustituir", sustituir);
    }else{
        sketchIntent.putExtra("BoulderKeyForSwitchFirstImage", BoulderKey);
        sketchIntent.putExtra("Uri", ImageUri);
        sketchIntent.putExtra("photoKey", photoKey);
        sketchIntent.putExtra("sustituir", sustituir);
    }
    startActivity(sketchIntent);

}
```

Comment: Have you checked activity launch mode?
please add manifest and the code that starts the activity

Comment: @IslamAssem Hi, I update the post with all the calls I do to arrive to the final activity, about manifest what do you want to see exactly, 'cause is a big one

Comment: no problem I posted a solution please check it, Thanks.

Comment: Already done thanks a lot, I feel I little bit stupid after figured out hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start SketchActivity you are using flags

```
 sketchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

and these flags close all previous activities and start the activity in a new task.
so to keep old previous activities please remove this line.

if you don't know what is a task, the task is the container for activities, so when you start new task this means that the activity is the first activity if you want to read more about tasks follow this link : 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

and you can find more information about intent flags here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you enabled developer mode (System -> Developer options), and it is force-closing the Activity?

There's an option (Developer Options, under 'apps', I'm using a Pixel 3) called 'Don't keep Activities' which should be disabled.

Comment: Everything is okey, both features; background proccess limit (standard limit) and don't keep activities (not selected) are in default mode